# Flutter build apk: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: flutter, gradle, build, apk

I installed flutter a few moments ago but I get this error when I want to run the flutter project:

```
 Building with sound null safety


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       6.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXVwV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your build gradle file. Most likely you added  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` in the wrong place. it should be added to `android/build.gradle` and not to `android/app/build.gradle`

Should look like this:

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
.
.
.
}
```